# Do not fire visibilitychange event on document reloads(refresh, page navigation) but fire on close browser, close tab, or switch tab

Tags: javascript, document, visibilitychange

```
  document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onVisibilityChange, {
    passive: true,
  });
```

This will fire even when someone navigates away from my page. Ofcourse this is logical. But is there a way to check if someone navigates away?

Edit: What i want is to listen if the user switches to another tab or places the window in the background, or close tab or browser. This works with visibilityChange but also fires when the user reloads the page or navigates back and forth in the history. But those are the behavior when I don't want to fire the event

Comment: Do you mean if the user change active tab ?

Comment: I think that this link can help you : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState

The visibility state must be what you are looking for

Comment: @horhorou Yeah i am using that. And that works great. Only it also fires when you reload the page. I don't want that. So i am looking for a way to intercept router changes or something

Comment: Maybe you can combine this with the window.onload or the window.location

Comment: You should listen to `pagehide` event, it fires before `visibilitychange`. If `pagehide` has been fired then the page is being unloaded.

Comment: I'm facing the reverse of it. I want the `visibilitychange` event to fire up upon reloads and back and forth navigation. But that's not happening. Any clues?

Answer (score -1):

You can use setTimeout, code in setTimeout won't run on reload.

```
  function handleVisibilityChange (e) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
            console.log('HIDDEN')
        } else {
            console.log('VISIBLE')
        }
    }, 0)
}
```